# Add more button Webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I'm trying to add a "add more" button on my webform. I tried "Webform Add More" module, but I need to add fields as user request instead of show and hide fields as user request another one. Is there any way to programmatically add fields to webform in a custom module?

I can't make a webform with the same field repeated 30 times if a user want to submit 30 different items.

I'm currently using Webform 3.18 and Drupal 7.38

Thanks for the help.

Comment: How about making one field with input separated by something?

Comment: So, show the same item repeatedly with jQuery, and add the values consecutive as a text separated by a pipe for example ?

Comment: In matter of fact, I wasn't thinking that far (jQuery), but sounds good. If you want to manipulate the data after submission. there is a [hook_webform_submission_insert](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!webform.api.php/function/hook_webform_submission_insert/7)

Comment: It seems to be a good solution, but If I want to display different values associated to that "item" field or make submission mail and submission results table understandable, I have to manipulate 3 different templates. So if I could add fields to the webform itself, it would be easy to understand as for the customers and for the store admin, the submission results table and submission email.

Comment: The only problem is, all changes in form structure will be global for all users